# Vcard MMS file name is always "text 1"

Tags: twilio

When sending a vcard file on an SMS message via Twilio using the mediaUrl option, it shows up on the iPhone with "text 1" next to the file as if "text 1" is the file name.

I have tried renaming the vcard file, using example vcard files, etc. No matter what the files show up as "text 1".

[image: Example vcf]

I have tried on iPhone 8 and 10. I have tried bare bones VCF files and full featured ones from Outlook and even example ones online such as http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-examples/john-doe.vcf - No matter what, they show up on iPhone as "text 1".

What can I do to make this be either the phone number or a name?

Edit --- After the comment from @philnash, I was able to add a content-disposition header to the file which now comes back in the headers as follows:

```
 Content-Disposition: attachment; name="John Doe"; filename="john-doe.vcf"
```

Here is a screenshot from Fiddler:
[image: Fiddler screenshot]

I also renamed the file to a unique name and tried again in case Twilio or anywhere along the way was caching the old file. The header is there but the message still shows "text 1" on the iPhone.

In case it had something to do with Azure blob storage. I also coded an ASP.Net MVC file action that returns the file with the content dispostion headers - it also shows as "text 1" on iPhone. 
[image: IIS server]

Comment: Did you get it figured out?  Where did you set the header at? @ericdc

Comment: I've tried every answer and it doesn't appear to work for Google Messages, I suspect there is a bug on their end as it works for iOS/Samsung message apps. Link to Google Support if they fix it https://support.google.com/messages/thread/246907583?hl=en&sjid=13813631906242855464-NC

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When Twilio provides the metadata for the MMS it does so based on the `Content-Disposition` header it gets when requesting the media from the URL you provide. When there isn't one available, it gets set to something generic, like "text 1" in this instance.

To overcome this, you need to set the `Content-Disposition` response header on the file you are serving. Within this header, you can declare a name and a filename. I haven't been able to test this (I'm not in the US, so can't receive the MMS from Twilio) but I would guess that the name is used, though I would test with filename too.

The header should look a bit like this:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; name="John Doe"; filename="john-doe.vcf"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to add a content-disposition header to the file which now comes back in the headers as this but still does not work
     Content-Disposition: attachment; name="John Doe"; filename="john-doe.vcf"

Here is a screenshot from Fiddler:
https://www.screencast.com/t/ibYfN79HqN 

I also renamed the file to a unique name and tried again in case Twilio or anywhere along the way was caching the old file. The header is there but the message still shows "text 1". Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I may be mistaken about using the `name` directive in the header. Try with only `filename`. Also, this is a vcard that we have tested and does work, with the name "Ashton", could you try this too? https://media.twiliocdn.com/AC648d937704b94309822578b85ff1227f/9e4be3b88b54293a158beb296a8841cb

Comment: I downloaded your example file, put it on my server - and it came through with the name "Ashton" - not the full name of Ashton Jones - just "Ashton".

I then edited that file and changed one letter in the name to make it "Ashlon" and it came in as "text 1". I changed it back and it came as "Ashton". I then tried changing one number in the phone number from a 1 to a 2 and it again came in as "text 1". - So it worked with your exact file unchanged. I tried probably 50 variations of this.

I updated my iPhone to 12.2 and now these come in right - even Ashton says Ashton Jones.

Comment: Well, I am fairly lost as to the cause there. Do your original tests work with iOS 12.2 too?

Comment: Its back to "text 1" randomly. Unreal.

Comment: That is bizarre and I'm not sure what to suggest any more!

Comment: Dumb question here but where does one set the  Content-Disposition: attachment; name="John Doe"; filename="john-doe.vcf"?  Is it in the actual file?

Comment: @FabricioG It depends on what you are using to serve the file. It could be in your web server config (like Apache or nginx), in your web application server (like Express in Node) or in your static file store (like s3). It's not in the file itself though.

Comment: Did you actually get this to work? I'm still getting text 1 or text 0. I ensured that my server serving the vcf is returning back all the Content-Disposition content as explained.

Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="James-Lo3-a.vcf"
Content-Type: text/x-vcard

Comment: I'm afraid I've got nothing further I can add @code5. I'm also not in the US or Canada, so can't test sending vcards to my own device.

Comment: Hi @philnash I got it to work. Definitely caching has something to do with it. I can upload to my CDN new content every time with the same physical file name. This is part is very important as you explained:  Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Disposition: inline; filename="the name you want to show.vcf" Content-Type: text/x-vcard

Comment: @code5 your approach of just setting Content-Disposition: inline; filename="...", without adding name="..." as well. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I tested this some as I was having the same issue.  It appears once a Vcard has been sent, subsequent sends of the same Vcard result in text 1 being sent for the name of the Vcard.  However, for sends to new recipients sends with the name.  ...at least from my tests.

Comment: yeah...this was wrong.  Upon further testing my users began only seeing "text 1".

Answer (score 2):

I spent a long time troubleshooting this. I was almost going to give up. But then I sent my own contact through mms from my phone to a number controlled by twilio so I could see what headers Twilio was capturing when originating directly from an iphone. That's when I noticed this important header:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="what-to-show.vcf"
```

The key here is the "inline" argument, "attachment" doesn't work. Then my stuff came over on iOS just as I wanted. ("what-to-show" instead of "text 1"). Perfect!

Comment: After lots more testing, we found that inline was better too. Thanks.

Comment: Where would I set that Content-Disposition?  @Nef

Comment: @philnash hi Phil by any chance do you have an example of where exactly the Content-Disposition goes?

Comment: Did you actually get this to work? I'm still getting text 1 or text 0. I ensured that my server serving the vcf is returning back all the Content-Disposition content, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No fix, just adding that this experience also is replicated on Android 9 (Pie). The only discrepancy with the above is that the file is "text_1".

Comment: Upon further digging, I see that there may be a difference in the casing. Using the above listed "Ashton" example, the headers come back as `content-disposition: attachment; filename="Ashton.vcf"` and `content-type: text/vcard`, instead of something more like `Content-type: text/vcard`. I know HTTP headers are supposed to be case insensitive, but apache sometimes makes this an issue. Food for thought.