# How to set Headers in twilio mms

Tags: express, twilio

I'm sending a message in twilio like so:

```
   const client = require('twilio')(
      process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
      process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN,
    );

app.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  client.messages
    .create({
      from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
      to: '13105551212',
      body: req.body.message,
      mediaUrl: ['http://codesto.net/eadlapmesssaging.vcf'],
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.send({ success: true });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.send({ success: false });
    });
});
```

Since I'm sending a vcard I've read that I should set the "Content-Disposition". This is posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387816/vcard-mms-file-name-is-always-text-1)
in the header.  I can't find anywhere in the documentations where I would do that.  I'm not even sure how to set the headers for a message.  Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: There is nothing of that sort in their docs. You only have to enable MMS capability when buying your phone number. Read more here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-node-js

Comment: But there is a problem when sending a vcard.  You can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387816/vcard-mms-file-name-is-always-text-1. @riazosama there they talk about setting the Content-Disposition.

Answer (score 0):

the supported MIME types can be found here, [Accepted Content Types for Media](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types), you can set the MIME type returned by Express following along in this blog, [Work with HTTP headers in Express](https://flaviocopes.com/express-headers/) and a similar process can be followed to set the `Content-Disposition` header.

I personally found the representations of vcard's to be fiddly over MMS across different mobile devices.

Please share your experience once you get everything set-up.