# My curl HTTP POST request is retrieving a pdf file without its file name

Tags: json, http, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, twilio

When running a curl POST to send a PDF file through Twilio API in WhatsApp, it is sent without its file name. It is sent as untitled. I checked with multiple PDF files hosted on multiple different websites. I filled in all its metadata and properties also. But the problem continues to be here with me.

This is the request:

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json \
  --data-urlencode "To=whatsapp:+11111111" \
  --data-urlencode "From=whatsapp:+11111111" \
  --data-urlencode "MediaUrl=https://gentl.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/kenko-menu.pdf" \
  -u 'ACxxxxxxxxxxx:auth_token'
```

I used postman to check which were the HTTP response and I found nothing strange. These were:

```
{"sid": "MMxxxxxxxx", "date_created": "Thu, 19 Nov 2020 23:51:34 +0000", "date_updated": "Thu, 19 Nov 2020 23:51:34 +0000", "date_sent": null, "account_sid": "ACxxxxxxxx", "to": "whatsapp:+11111111", "from": "whatsapp:+11111111", "messaging_service_sid": null, "body": "", "status": "queued", "num_segments": "1", "num_media": "1", "direction": "outbound-api", "api_version": "2010-04-01", "price": null, "price_unit": null, "error_code": null, "error_message": null, "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxx/Messages/MMxxxxxxxx.json", "subresource_uris": {"media": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxx/Messages/MMxxxxxxx/Media.json"}}
```

Also, this is a screenshot of the response headers.[image: Screenshot of response headers]

I would reeeeeeally appreciate your help in coming up with a solution. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently Twilio doesn't support setting a filename or caption for documents sent as media messages over WhatsApp.

If we were to support it in the near future, it should work in a similar way to [setting filenames for MMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55388983/28376). You should do so by setting the `Content-Disposition` header on your file to `attachment` or `inline` plus a name and filename, like:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; name="Kenko Menu"; filename="kenko-menu.pdf"
```

As I type this, this won't work. But you can likely future proof your application by applying a header like that now.

Comment: Thank you! And I'm guessing there is no other solution than waiting, right?

Comment: Yep, I'm afraid you won't be able to set the filename through the Twilio API for WhatsApp until it is supported so you will have to wait for now.